# Can Not get Image from firebase because replace string to variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, firebase-storage

I can get image from fire store with fixed file name by following code

```
        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storageReference = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("xxxx.com/");
        StorageReference image = storageReference.Child("path/filename.jpg");
```

Than I try to get same file by input filename

```
inputBoxContent = inputBox.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        string fileName = "path/"+inputBoxContent.text+".jpg";
        Debug.Log(fileName);
        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storageReference = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("xxxx.com/");
        StorageReference image = storageReference.Child(fileName);
```

I replace `("path/filename.jpg")`to `string fileName = "textileimages/"+inputBoxContent.text+".jpg"`  `StorageReference image = storageReference.Child(fileName);` than it doesn't work, I try `fileName.ToString()`it didn't work either , but the `Debug.Log(fileName);` show the right string , have no idea , please help ;(

Comment: Have you tried placing a `Debug.Assert(inputBoxContent.text == "filename", "Does not match!");` to be sure the input is correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply , I add debug.assert(file name == “path/file name.jpg”, “no match”),it show no match, weird. How’s that¿ I use debug.log , it seems match…

Comment: Maybe some spaces? Or maybe some invisible character?

Comment: You're going to have to gain some clarity on what exactly the value of `inputBoxContent.text` is.  It must not be what you think.  We can't see what it is, and we can see that it matches the name of any object in Storage that you're trying to work with.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson you gave me a good direction , the problem is input field I use is TMPPRO , and it will add a space at the end , https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-there-is-no-setting-for-textmesh-pro-ugui-to-count-whitespace-at-the-end.676897/  I change to old version of input field , problem solved

Answer (score 0):

the problem is input field I use is TMPPRO , and it will add a space at the end , https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-there-is-no-setting-for-textmesh-pro-ugui-to-count-whitespace-at-the-end.676897/  I change to old version of input field , problem solved